# How to create asynchronous iterator in golang - but currently deadlocking

Tags: go, deadlock, goroutine

I have this which I have faith is close to working as desired. What I am trying to do is range over a sequence, but be able to call the next item yourself and asynchronously

sync:

```
for r := range even.Sequence() {
    if !r.Done {
        r.Contnue()
    }
}
```

or async:

```
   for r := range even.Sequence() {
        go func(){
          if !r.Done {
            r.Contnue()
           }
        }()
    }
```

here is the full code in main:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type HasNext[T any] interface {
    Next() (bool, T)
}

type Nexter[T int] struct {
    Val int
    End int
}

type Ret struct {
    Done    bool
    Value   int
    Contnue func()
}

func (n *Nexter[int]) Sequence() chan Ret {

    var c = make(chan Ret)
    even := newEven()

    var x func()

    x = func() {
        fmt.Println("got here 3")
        <-c
        fmt.Println("got here 4")
        fmt.Println("got here 5")
        var b, v = even.Next()
        c <- Ret{b, v, x}
        if b {
            close(c)
        }
    }

    go func() {
        var b, v = even.Next()
        fmt.Println("got here 1")
        c <- Ret{b, v, x}
        fmt.Println("got here 2")
    }()

    return c

}

func (n *Nexter[int]) Next() (bool, int) {
    n.Val = n.Val + 1
    if n.Val > n.End {
        return true, int(n.Val)
    }
    return false, int(n.Val)
}

func newEven() *Nexter[int] {
    n := 0
    return &Nexter[int]{n, 5}
}

func main() {


    even := newEven()


    for r := range even.Sequence() {

        fmt.Println("value:", r.Value)
        if !r.Done {
            fmt.Println("continuing...")
            r.Contnue()
        }
    }

}
```

but currently I get this output:

> ```
> got here 1
> got here 2
> value: 1
> continuing...
> got here 3
> fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
>
> goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
> main.main()
>         /Users/me/codes/vibeirl/wss/test/iterator/main.go:83 +0x66
> ```

so clearly it's deadlocking somewhere but not sure where/how exactly

Answer (score -1):

Got it to work, I was trying to read from the channel myself, but realized that (obviously) range reads from the channel by its nature:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type HasNext[T any] interface {
    Next() (bool, T)
}

type Nexter[T int] struct {
    Val int
    End int
}

type Ret struct {
    Done    bool
    Value   int
    Contnue func()
}

func (n *Nexter[int]) Sequence() chan Ret {

    var c = make(chan Ret, 1)
    even := newEven()
    var isClosed = false

    var x func()

    x = func() {
        if isClosed {
            fmt.Println("warning channel closed")
            return
        }
        var b, v = even.Next()
        if b {
            isClosed = true
        }
        c <- Ret{b, v, x}
        if b {
            close(c)
        }
    }

    go func() {
        var b, v = even.Next()
        c <- Ret{b, v, x}
    }()

    return c

}

func (n *Nexter[int]) Next() (bool, int) {
    n.Val = n.Val + 1
    if n.Val >= n.End {
        return true, int(n.Val)
    }
    return false, int(n.Val)
}

func newEven() *Nexter[int] {
    n := 0
    return &Nexter[int]{n, 5}
}

func main() {

    even := newEven()

    for r := range even.Sequence() {

        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 500)

        fmt.Println("value:", r.Value)

        if !r.Done {
            r.Contnue()
        }


    }

}
```

couple of things I wonder about - if isClosed needs to protected by a lock, but it's not easy for me to figure out how to do that

Comment: if `isClosed` is not accessed from concurrent goroutines (which it isn't), then there's no need for a mutex to protect concurrent access (but the logic around `isClosed` isn't really needed at all). As for the iterator, with the buffered channel the goroutine isn't needed, and the channel API just makes a more awkward version of the standard iterator pattern. There's nothin particularly "asynchronous" about this.

Comment: logic with isClosed is needed otherwise it will try to write to the closed channel here `c <- Ret{b, v, x}`, it's just protecting the operator from a panic

Comment: @JimB it is an async iterator that's controlled by the user inside the loop, notice that r.Continue can be called asynchronously, and the fact that's also required to be called by the operator in order to iterate.

Comment: Printing a warning while ignoring a logical error is not a resilient pattern. You can't get to that case without a programming error, it should panic if the API is misused. Yes, `r.Continue` could be called asynchronously, but so could _anything_, the only asynchronous bit is the initial goroutine which returns before any work is done actually by the iterator. There's nothing shown here which warrants the extra channel and logic compared with a standard iterator.

Comment: it's not a logical error, it would be when they accidentally fire a callback more than once; in most good software the 2nd or 3rd callback would be ignored, since a bug from that would be annoying to track down